# Send-MailMessage : The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The

Tags: email, powershell, office365

First time poster - I've been googling this all week! I'm fairly new to Powershell and I'm trying to utilise Send-MailMessage. The objective is to set a Powershell script on a scheduled task to send out an automated email. I know setting a Powershell script as a scheduled task has it's own nuances which I have researched and I think I know what to do next in regards to that but before I even get to that point I keep running across the following error when I call the script:

> Send-MailMessage : The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server
>   response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString “PASSWORD” -AsPlainText -Force

$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "user@domain.com", $secpasswd

Send-MailMessage -To "user@domain.com" -Subject "Subject" -SmtpServer "smtp.office365.com" -Credential $mycreds -UseSsl -Port "587" -From "user@domain.com"
```

I'm trying to send the message using Office 365 (as you can see from the SMTP server). This works fine when I copy and paste it directly into the console but when I try to call the script using the following command it shows the above error.

```
Powershell.exe -File C:\my_path\Script.ps1
```

Is there something that I'm missing? Possibly a better way of calling the script which authenticates it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been staring at various forum posts for days now! :)

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at my Github Gist for this [Click Here](https://gist.github.com/SteloNLD/8ade5b04b326cb437d5041e0a46f7fa1) or see example below.

I had the same issue and is seems that this is a generic error message, most of the time i get this message when i entered a wrong password, but i believe not having SendAs rights gave the same error, the Port , SMTPServer and UseSSL Parameters in the example are configured for Office365 which i just tested and it works.

Also note that i provided an example for Secure Strings, you should use this if you want to store passwords securely in your script files.

```
### Script Global Settings
#Declare SMTP Connection Settings
$SMTPConnection = @{
    #Use Office365, Gmail, Other or OnPremise SMTP Relay FQDN
    SmtpServer = 'outlook.office365.com'

    #OnPrem SMTP Relay usually uses port 25 without SSL
    #Other Public SMTP Relays usually use SSL with a specific port such as 587 or 443
    Port = 587 
    UseSsl = $true    

    #Option A: Query for Credential at run time.
    Credential = Get-Credential -Message 'Enter SMTP Login' -UserName "emailaddress@domain.tld"

    <#
    #Option B: Hardcoded Credential based on a SecureString
    Credential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList @( 

        #The SMTP User Emailaddress
        "emailaddress@domain.tld"

        #The Password as SecureString encoded by the user that wil run this script!
        #To create a SecureString Use the folowing Command: Read-Host "Enter Password" -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString
        "Enter the SecureString here as a single line" | ConvertTo-SecureString
    ) 
    #> 
}

### Script Variables
#Declare Mailmessages.
$MailMessageA = @{
    From = "emailaddress@domain.tld"
    To = @(
        "emailaddress@domain.tld"
    )
    #Cc = @(
    #    "emailaddress@domain.tld"
    #)
    #Bcc = @(
    #    "emailaddress@domain.tld"
    #)

    Subject = 'Mailmessage from script'
    #Priority = 'Normal' #Normal by default, options: High, Low, Normal
    #Attachments = @(
        #'FilePath'    
    #)
    #InlineAttachments = @{
        #'CIDA'='FilePath'
    #} #For more information about inline attachments in mailmessages see: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Send-MailMessage-3a920a6d

    BodyAsHtml = $true    
    Body = "Something Unexpected Occured as no Content has been Provided for this Mail Message!" #Default Message
}

### Script Start

#Retrieve Powershell Version Information and store it as HTML with Special CSS Class
$PSVersionTable_HTLM = ($PSVersionTable.Values | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment) -replace '<table>', '<table class="table">'

#Retrieve CSS Stylesheet
$CSS = Invoke-WebRequest "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/advancedrei/BootstrapForEmail/master/Stylesheet/bootstrap-email.min.css" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content

#Build HTML Mail Message and Apply it to the MailMessage HashTable
$MailMessageA.Body = ConvertTo-Html -Title $MailMessageA.Subject -Head "<style>$($CSS)</style>" -Body "
    <p>
        Hello World,    
    </p>

    <p>
        If your recieved this message then this script works.</br>
        </br>
        <div class='alert alert-info' role='alert'>
            Powershell version
        </div>
        $($PSVersionTable_HTLM)
    </P>
" | Out-String


#Send MailMessage
#This example uses the HashTable's with a technique called Splatting to match/bind the Key's in the HashTable with the Parameters of the command.
#Use the @ Symbol instead of $ to invoke Splatting, Splatting improves readability and allows for better management and reuse of variables
Send-MailMessage @SMTPConnection @MailMessageA
```